# How to destroy all gameobjects over a specified position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

I am trying to clone the Helix Jump game as a game project by myself and I encountered a general problem. I am instantiating new platforms as the ball moves down and want to destroy those platforms which are already out of the camera angle. I can destroy them one by one but what if I want to remove all objects over a specified position.y value? There might be other objects than platforms for different games.

EDIT: I learned that we cannot add the current scene camera to the prefab's script as a parameter.

That is DestroyOutOfBounds.cs that I wrote but it does not work since I could not bind the main camera to the script.

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(Math.Abs(gameCam.transform.position.y - transform.position.y) > 10.0f) {
        Destroy(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can get the main camera for a scene via `Camera.main`: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html - not entirely sure if that is what you are asking about

Comment: that helps a lot. if I can take the main camera, my script works, and it works. But my script is so simple and it brings some responsibility while spawning since if I spawn them far away than 10.0f they will never spawn again but anyway. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

To do that you can [BoxCast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.BoxCast.html) specified area and by getting objects collider you can destroy them. For this method to work all the objects you want to destroy must have some kind of collider.

The method:

```
private void DestrayObjectsInArea((int, int) area)
{
    RaycastHit2D ray;
    while (true)
    {
        ray = Physics2D.BoxCast(transform.position, new Vector2(area.Item1, area.Item2), 0f, Vector2.right);
        if (ray.collider != null)
            Destroy(ray.collider.gameObject);
        else
            break;
    } 
}
```

Comment: that's an interesting approach. I will look for its 3d version. thanks